# How to add Latest Post Of Category Show in the Detail Article

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Views.py

```
def PostView(request,slug):
    Postdata = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    side_data = Post.objects.all()
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category__cat_slug=slug)
    return render(request,'post-detail.html',{'Postdata':Postdata,'side_data':side_data,'category_posts':category_posts})
```

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category_description = FroalaField()
    cat_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

options = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='myapp_post')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = FroalaField()
    feature_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/', null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default='draft')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Post-detail.html

```
<h4>Related Post</h4>
<br>
{% for data in category_posts %}
  <h4>{{data.title}}</h4>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to Add Category Related latest Posts in the Article.

For Example

If an article in which category name is Django Tutorial. In the Article Detail, I want to add the Related latest post of this category.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by('-id')[0]
```

order by id will give you the last one added
or you can use directly :

```
Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).last()
```